# Product Image are not accessible...

Tags: magento, webserver

We are using Magento ver1.6.1 to develop a website.

When try upload images for products, the images are not view-able. When check through FTP images are uploaded properly in server.

When try to access images under media folder, it through 500 error and image under root dir are loading properly.

Anybody guess where the issue occurs, Magento or Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a server problem check the folder permission 777 was set

Answer (score 4):

1. Try to chmod 644 or 755 media folder
2. Try to rename media/.htaccess file
3. Pay a billion of dollar to magento solution partner :)

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 is a Web Server's internal error so you might want to start with server logs.  On Ubuntu at

```
/var/log/apache/
/var/log/httpd/
```

(sorry don't remember off the top of my head) but the location depends on your OS and web server.  Beyond that you would need to post the error that the server reports.